# Is there a scriptable browser for node.js?

Tags: node.js, browser

I'm looking for a http/https wrapper library, which would be preserving cookies and otherwise replicating a normal browser.

I'm aware of zombie.js and phantom.js, but don't need JS support and would prefer something lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Tobi](https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi) is what you're looking for, besides things for a normal browser it does support cookies:

> Tobi allows you to test your web application as if it were a browser.
>   Interactions with your app are performed via jsdom, htmlparser, and
>   jQuery, in combination with Tobi's Cookie Jar, provides a natural
>   JavaScript API for traversing, manipulating and asserting the DOM, and
>   session based browsing.

Comment: It seems to need a new browser for each domain and a path for each request. Is there anything I can just throw a URL at and let it do the thinking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "let it do the thinking"..?

Comment: Well, to parse the domain and the port itself, having some defaults, like 80 and 443 depending on the protocol. I've tried tobi already, but couldn't even get anything from Google...